# How slow/fast is String concatenation in Java relative to other compiled languages?

Tags: java, benchmarking

I'm just getting started with Java and while reading through [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration) I noticed the following snippet, describing a recent update to the Junit framework.

> We can now write assertion messages in a lambda in JUnit 5, allowing
>   the lazy evaluation to skip complex message construction until needed:
>
> ```
> @Test
> public void shouldFailBecauseTheNumbersAreNotEqual_lazyEvaluation() {
>     Assertions.assertTrue(
>       2 == 3, 
>       () -> "Numbers " + 2 + " and " + 3 + " are not equal!");
> }
> ```

As someone new to Java this feels like a large implementation just to get around string concatenation.

Are evaluating strings in Java really that slow (relative to other languages?). How does it compare to other compiled languages like C, Golang, etc..?

Comment: This seems like a trivial example as String concatenation is turned into a bunch of `append()` calls to a StringBuilder.  But if, for example, you had a method call that was a bit more expensive to call to do the logging then it might matter.

Comment: String concatination is not slow, but it _was_ memory inperformant, as the you hat `number_of_string ^ 2` string instances in the memory. And creating new string instances takes time. Time that would not be needed if no new instance would be created. But since a long time, the compiler will replace string concatination with StringBuffer / StringBuilder, which is not memory inperformant anymore.

Comment: But keep in mind, string concatination within a loop should always be done with StringBuilder on your own, as the the compiler will create a new instance on each itteration, and reusing one instance is way more performant.

Comment: It is precisely 3ms slower than C++, 6.4ns slower than Python, 0.0000000000003 fortnights faster than GoLang, 3 jiffies faster than Perl, and 5 nanocenturies slower than [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). Perfectly cromulent performance, if you ask me

Comment: This example is a poor one, because the string is a compile-time constant. As such, there is no runtime cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is: there is no *lazy* string formatting in Java.

Meaning, in languages like C you might see things such as:

```
#define debug_print...
```

( see some real world examples [here](http://outube.com) )

The idea is to define a macro to which you pass a complicated string. But the compiler makes sure that code gets only generated for situations that actually that string to be present.

Meaning: when using `debug_print()`, that complicated string concat that is might be required to build the messages passed to the macro call  **only** happens when the message is really needed! The message is concatenated lazily.

In Java, we simply have no way to express that. You always have to go

```
if (someCondition) {
  then pull together that large string
```

which isn't nice, especially when doing it for tracing. Some people in our group write that code, and it is just overly annoying that each and any trace statement has that leading if statement. That renders your whole code much less readable.

Therefore: this is **not at all** about the cost of string concats. It is about **only** spending the required CPU cycles if that string is truly needed.

And to answer the actual question: in the end, when that code gets invoked often enough, the JIT will turn it into carefully optimized machine code anyway. Thus: the actual string concat is **not** the issue.

In other words: you don't think of "performance" for Java in terms of *source code*. What matters is what happens at runtime, by the JIT.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So it seems purely about saving CPU cycles, so my followup question would be "is it really worth adding the more code (from a purely theoretical point) versus saving those cycles?" I'm guessing the answer will be what hardware your using, how much you're trying to optimize, etc...

Comment: @user2490003: There's very little "in theory" when it comes to tradeoffs between maintainability / readability vs. performance when those are at odds with each other (when the language makes it hard to do efficiently, or your C++ compiler needs help finding optimizations).  It always depends on the codebase and what you want to use it for.  I think in this case it's an idiom you can easily get used to, though.

Comment: @user2490003 It is really not easy. When our system is up and running, and the really **huge** tasks are triggered, then we have millions of trace messages coming into our trace utility within a few minutes. A full trace of our most expensive operation results in *gigabytes* of data easily. So yeah: having these if/then checks in place is ugly. Not using them in situations where you have/want to trace important information ... also a big problem. Especially when these traces are invoked zillions of times. Very careful balancing required then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bottom line. Starting out in Java, don't worry about minor performance issues like String concatenation. It may be a small issue for a large application server where lots of String concatenation is done but the results are not used. An example would be logging, where the log level of causes the event to be ignored. Also, Java uses a StringBuilder to concatenate a series of literals separated by the "+' operator, which is reasonably performant.